# Bounding the variance of a stopping time

Tags: martingales, variance, stopping-times

Please refer to the exact same setting of this question:

[Durret problem 4.8.3 - Random walk and optional sampling theorem application](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3431252/durret-problem-4-8-3-random-walk-and-optional-sampling-theorem-application?rq=1)

I repeat the setting here in any case:

> Let $S_n = \xi_1+\ldots+\xi_n$, $(\xi_i)_i$ independent with $0$ mean
> and $Var(\xi_i)=\sigma^2$. Then $S^2_n−n\sigma^2$ is a martingale. Let
> consider the stopping time $T=\inf \{n:|S_n|>a\}$.
>
> Show $\mathbb{E}[T]>\frac{a^2}{\sigma^2}$.

Is there an expression that corresponds to $Var(T)$? Or at least an upper bound for $Var(T)$?

For example, if we are dealing with a symmetric simple random walk, then we can get an expression for $Var(T)$. See for example:

[Stopping time computations via martingales](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/355432/stopping-time-computations-via-martingales)

What about the more general case stated in the first link? I have tried to follow a similar approach, trying to come up with some clever martingale and apply the optional stopping theorem, but so far to no avail.

Thanks!

Comment: I would suspect you need control on more moments of $\xi_n$, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Suppose you could control further moments. What approaches do you think are worth a try?